# Microsoft Visual studio 2012 in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, visual-c++

lately I shift my work from windows to Ubuntu,
the problem is 
I was use a Microsoft Visual studio 2012
now I don't know how to install in Ubuntu.

Comment: Duplicate but I can't flag because its a SE thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/266842/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012-in-ubuntu

Comment: Short answer: you can't install MS Visual Studio in Ubuntu

Comment: Why was this tagged as C#? It's purely a question about the tool.

Comment: because I want to use C# and VC++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that it's as simple as just installing the same version of visual studio on Ubuntu. The simplest solution would probably be to just use a virtual machine. There are also other versions of Visual Studio available, such as [Visual Studio Code](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), that'll work directly on Linux.

Please also see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio) for some other suggestions.